# Interactive Chess Whiteboard

Tags: chessboards, clubs

I am a coach at a small high school. We are starting a chess club. We have Epson BrightLink projectors with the interactive boards. Is there a way we can have a chess board displayed on the whiteboard that allows a finger to move pieces while also using a pen to annotate? An example can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2SARMDtDv8).

Comment: Is the projector connected to a computer? If so, you could try installing any chess program (or using a website) there. I don't know if you could add text annotations that way, but at least symbols should work if they are available through the GUI.

Comment: The projector is connected to a computer, and we have displayed a chess game through the projector, but in the Youtube video, the woman actually moves the chess pieces with her finger touching the board. I'm asking if anyone knows how to set that up.

Comment: Do they provide a sample application or a demo with the Epson BrightLink? It should not be to difficult to use.

Comment: Question. Why do you need touch feedback controls? Your students will get better at notation if you force them to call out the candidate moves and you update the board on your computer, yes? If you want a fun toy for the students, you could get a large-screened tablet or a normal display board.

Comment: Standing at the board and using fingers to move the pieces will keep the mind more engaged than just sitting and speaking. This is just my opinion, and from what I've observed while teaching. Later when we learn the formal chess notation, I can have them call it out as they move the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the chessboard on https://szachydzieciom.pl/?page_id=61146 in full screen mode (click the full screen icon). I know that in some schools in Poland it works well with touch whiteboards. But dragging pieces may not work. Instead you should tap the piece to move and then disconnect your hand and tap the target square separately.